# Elastic APM - Linking to transaction logs

Tags: elastic-apm

I am using the elastic apm java agent to publish tracing information to an elastic apm server. I am setting the `enable_log_correlation` property to true which makes the span, trace and transaction ids available in the MDC and using logstash to capture all that in an elastic index. The logs are visible in the Discover tab in elastic and tracing information is visible in the APM tab. I have seen in some screenshots a link on the APM > Transactions page to `View Transaction in Discover` to be able the see all logs related to a single transaction. This link is not showing up for me. The span link `Show span in Discover` is showing up and it takes you to Discover and opens up the apm index for this span. So two questions:

1. What do I need to do for the *View transaction in discover* link to show up?
2. Can the link open up an index other than apm- in Discover? Ideally, I want to see the application logs related to this transaction, not the apm logs.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Did you get answer? https://discuss.elastic.co/t/configure-app-logging-in-apm/302019/8